# How do you pull a php variable into a js object's property via jQuery AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I want the user to type an answer ('zebra') in the input area. If they get it correct, then they are alerted that it is correct.

This answer will be pulled from a database eventually. For this simple example, I'm just pulling it into the object from another php file via jQuery AJAX.

It seems to pull in the php variable okay, but it still says 'incorrect answer' in the example I'm doing here =

https://michael-r-oneill.ie/development/random/Testing/testing.php

https://michael-r-oneill.ie/development/random/Testing/collectDataTesting.php

Below is the html / php file

```
    <!-- head -->

<head>
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <title>Testing</title>

</head>

<script>

var AnswerSubmitted;
var quizes;

function quizesFunction(animal) 
{quizes = [{bigPicture: animal},{bigPicture: 'tokyo'}]}

$(function() {

    $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: 'collectDataTesting.php',
            data: {},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {


                quizesFunction(data);


            }
            });



    $(document).on('click', '.submit', function() {

    AnswerSubmitted = $('#typedAnswer').val();

    if (AnswerSubmitted == quizes[0].bigPicture) 
    {
        $('.test').html('correct answer').css("color", "green");;
        $('.AnswerSubmitted')
            .html('Answer submitted is ' + AnswerSubmitted);
        $('.objectProperty')
            .html('Object property is now ' + quizes[0].bigPicture);
    }
    else 
    {
        $('.test').html('incorrect answer').css("color", "red");
        $('.AnswerSubmitted')
            .html('Answer submitted is ' + AnswerSubmitted);
        $('.objectProperty')
            .html('Object property is now ' + quizes[0].bigPicture);

    }
    });

});

</script>


<p class="objectProperty"></p>
<p class="AnswerSubmitted"></p>
<p class="test"></p>
<input type="text" id="typedAnswer" />
<button class="submit" id='AS'>enter</button>
```

Below is the 'collectDataTesting.php' php file I'm going to to collect the data

```
<?php   
    echo 'zebra';
?>
```

Comment: Kindly post what error you are receiving and what is your expected output.

Comment: Check your browser console to see what the servers response is (network tab). Generally, you should reply to ajax with json. This way, your object/array can be directly accessed by JavaScript.

Comment: What is your actual issue? You only say "I'm trying to...". What actually happens? Please edit your question to include a proper explanation of the issue you want us to help you with.

Comment: You should also verify that the `quizes` variable isn't empty (if the ajax request failed for some reason or haven't finished yet) before you're trying to access data from it.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right, then it looks like the `data` passed to `quizesFunction(data)` when the ajax request is completed *is not of the type that you expect*.

Remember that if you don't provide the `dataType` setting to $.ajax (which you don't), jQuery will try to "guess" the type for you (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

You can either set the `dataType` to `text` or simply follow the advice given by the other members and have PHP return JSON (which jQuery will interpet as a JavaScript object).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help! I've edited my problem a little so it's a little easier to understand. I changed the dataType to "text", but didn't seem to work. How can I get "PHP to return JSON, so jQuery will interpret it as a JS object" as you've recommended?

Answer (score 0):

So as recommended by a contributor above, I managed to begin solving this issue by replying back to AJAX with JSON.

Here are the updated testing pages =

https://michael-r-oneill.ie/development/random/Testing/testing3.php

https://michael-r-oneill.ie/development/random/Testing/collectDataTesting3.php

and code below =

html =

```
<p class="AnswerSubmitted"></p>
<p>Type 'dog' in the input area and hit enter</p>
<input type="text" id="typedAnswer" />
<button class="submit" id='AS'>Enter</button>
```

js =

```
var AnswerSubmitted;
var AnswerCollected;
var quizes = [{bigPictureAnsw: 'answer here', bigPHint : 'hint here'},
              {bigPictureAnsw: 'answer here', bigPHint : 'hint here'}]


$(function() {

    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'collectDataTesting3.php', 
        data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 


            var x = 0;
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {

            quizes[x].bigPicture = element.answer;
            quizes[x].bigPHint = element.hint;
            x++;



            });
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.submit', function() {

         AnswerSubmitted = $('#typedAnswer').val();

         if (AnswerSubmitted == quizes[0].bigPicture)
         {
          $('.AnswerSubmitted').html('correct answer'); 
         }
         else
         {
          $('.AnswerSubmitted').html('not correct');
         }

    });


});
```

external page ('collectDataTesting3') =

```
[ { "answer" : "dog", "hint" : "not a cat" },
  { "answer" : "dublin", "hint" : "capital city" }]
```